# Flash Actionscript 3.0 MovieClip Transitions (No Buttons)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

I have 3 mc_MovieClips.
Each clip is on a different frame of the same layer in the main scene.
I do not want to use a button to control the play.
On startup, I want Clip1(On Frame1) to play, and when that is finished, Clip2(On Frame2) will play and so on.

I am a very beginner and using Flash Professional CC and actionscript 3.0. The only help I can seem to find calls for global variables, which no longer seem to exist.

I can provide more information if needed, I am just a really big beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a `parent.nextFrame();` on the last frame of each MovieClip and a `stop();` on each frame of the parent clip (actual frames of your main scene).